# Routing error with alternative update method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

Ruby on rails 3.1.3

I'm trying to figure out the correct route to my change_password method of my users_controller.

I'm currently getting this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"change_password", :controller=>"users", :format=>#<User id: 1, email: "foo@bar.baz", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$lgmrRTYFUUrWStLl1Y.Oo.LqQ2Ybxa29YkDFw61/KG9O...", password_salt: "$2a$10$lgmrRTYFUUrWStLl1Y.Oo.", username: "foobar", created_at: "2012-01-07 23:02:29", updated_at: "2012-01-13 11:16:45", password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: "2012-01-08 12:23:30">}
```

In users_controller:

```
def change_password
      @user = current_user
      @user_password_matches = User.authenticate(@user.email, params[:current_password])
      if @user_password_matches.update_attributes(params[:user])
        login @user
        format.js   { render :js => "window.location = '#{settings_account_path}'" } 
        flash[:success] = "Password updated" 
      else
        format.js   { render :form_errors }

      end
    end
```

Inside view:

```
<%= form_for @user, :remote => true, :url => change_password_path(@user) do |f| %>
Current password: <%= password_field_tag :current_password, :placeholder => "Password"  %><br />
New password: <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password"  %><br />
Confirm password: <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Confirm Password"  %><br />
<%= f.submit 'update' %>
```

routes:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    put :change_password
  end
end
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :passwords
  resources :profiles


  root :to                   => "users#new"
  match 'success'            => "users#success"
  match 'login'              => "sessions#new"
  match 'logout'             => "sessions#destroy"
  match 'reset_password'     => "passwords#new"
  match 'setup_new_password' => "passwords#edit"
  match 'settings', :to      => "users#settings"


  match "/settings/account", :to => "users#account"
  match "/settings/edit_profile", :to => "profiles#edit_profile"


  match '/:username', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

All I'm intending to do is only update the attributes in db if users entered password (:current_password) successfully passes authentication (the same method I use to log in users which would confirm password matches the one stored in the db) and if it does take the params of users form , in this case the newly hashed password and store it in the db..

Kind regards

Comment: Are your three questions with similar titles all closely related?

Comment: what output does `rake routes` give on terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the wrong path name in your form, it's `change_password_user_path`, not `change_password_path`.

Use `rake routes` to see the names of your routes. Also, you don't need a custom route for this, check my answer to your previous question.